# Database date records ordered by week, month, 3-month using db query or php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with the payment records of members. Something like this:

```
    Payment Date     |   Amount
---------------------------------
2014-02-01 00:00:00  |     10
2014-02-21 00:00:00  |     10
2014-07-22 00:00:00  |     10
2014-08-16 00:00:00  |     10
2014-11-23 00:00:00  |     10
2015-03-17 00:00:00  |     10
2015-04-30 00:00:00  |     10
2015-06-11 00:00:00  |     10
2015-07-11 00:00:00  |     10
```

...ETC

Payment amounts can vary and will not always be '10'.

I need to get the records of the payments by week, month, trimester, and year BUT with the sum and the beginning of the cycle.

So for example by year, I need to get:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00 - 50   //timestamp of beginning of the year
2015-01-01 00:00:00 - 40   //and the sum of payments that year
```

Same way, for quarterly records, I need to get:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00 - 20   //timestamp of beginning 
2014-04-01 00:00:00 -  0   //of the trimester
2014-07-01 00:00:00 - 20   //and the sum of the payments
2014-10-01 00:00:00 - 10   //that trimester

2015-01-01 00:00:00 - 10   //timestamp of beginning 
2015-04-01 00:00:00 - 20   //of the trimester
2015-07-01 00:00:00 - 10   //and the sum of the payments that trimester
```

In order to solve this, I am considering 2 possible approaches:

```
1) Put together a mysql query (if it possibly exists) 

2) Get all the records from the user and just sort them with php
```

I am ready to go for the php solution, but is there a way it can be accomplished with a mysql query? If so, could you please guide me to the path to accomplish that query?

In addition, which solution would be more efficient/less time consuming?

I hope I make sense.

Comment: Certainly looks like payments are always 10

Comment: yeah I just wanted to make the illustration easier to see

Comment: It got it working neatly with @McAdam331 's reply! below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these groups using functions like `WEEK()`, `MONTH()`, `QUARTER()`. There are a whole list of date and time functions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

To get the counts per year, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(paymentDate), SUM(amount) AS totalAmount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY YEAR(paymentDate);
```

Then, you can use the `MAKEDATE` function to get the first day of the year:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(paymentDate), 1);
```

You may have to use `DATE_FORMAT` to configure the first day of a month/quarter, but you will find the necessary functions at the link I shared.

Comment: Thank you McAdam. Your code plus the link delivered me happiness. It all worked like a charm. Cheers!

Comment: @karlosdpm glad I could help! I was in a bit of a hurry, so I wasn't able to give an exact query, but I'm happy I got you close enough.

Comment: I took the hint and i made it happen. That is all is needed in most cases. Big Thanks!

Comment: I have this query which is working GREAT!
`SELECT MONTH(pay_dt) as month, YEAR(pay_dt) as year, SUM(amount) AS totalAmount, pay_dt FROM member_fee_payments WHERE member_id = '2' AND pay_dt > '2012-08-18 16:33:01' GROUP BY YEAR(pay_dt), MONTH(pay_dt); `
@McAdam It is returning beautifully the months where there are payments to show. But, is there exists the way to make it so it returns also months with amounts zero?  I have to displays also months with 0 amount in the user control panel  (kind of like banks do with statements). If not, I can do it with PHP. Thank you!!!

Comment: In order to do that, you will need to have a table with all month names, so you can preform an outer join. This is a very common problem, and is discussed often on SO. However, the first article I found was not from SO, but still relevant: https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/334766/select-query-to-results-all-12-months-even-if-data-not-exist

Comment: I will check that one out. Thank you for your help!